# How would I locate the correct IP address of another computer on my LAN which is not publicly accessible?

Tags: networking, java

I am writing a distributed Java app, but the networking side of things is stumping me. For some reason it's not working correctly. I think it's because the IP address I get through ipconfig /all is not accessible from outside the LAN. I appreciate any tips or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm??? "How would I locate the correct IP address of another computer on my LAN which is not publicly accessible?" and "I think it's because the IP address I get through ipconfig /all is not accessible from outside the LAN." appear to run opposite of each other. Which one is it?

Are you trying to identify IPs internally from within the same network or are you having accessibility issues from one network to another?

If it's the former, then an internal ICMP scan across the network is fairly easy or an ARP table read if it a system which has already made direct contact with the application system (or another local network device where its ARP table can be referenced/extracted from).

If it's the later, then you might consider providing some additional details that as to what is being attempted.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm trying to identify IPs internally from within the same network. I have to run a networked demo between 2 machines inside a university lab. So I should do an ICMP scan ? I'll look that up and do that! Thank You ,

Comment: That's typical for on a local network. You might also check with the network support folks to ensure there are no policies against scanning within the network. Some security folks and/or products may view that as a possible impending attack, but if it is legitimate, then coordinating that up front should take care of subject.

Comment: Glad that it is working out for you.